# Dynamic Cache name in service worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker

how create dynamic cache name in service worker?
I want to check API server to know the last version of my app. it will be cache name of my app.
I used fetch but it always return `undefined`,

```
staticCacheName = (() => {
    fetch('https://unitedspace.co.id/check_version.php')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(myJson => myJson.app_name + '-' + myJson.version + '.' + myJson.build_number);
})();
```

this is my service worker code :

```
self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) {
    e.waitUntil(caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
        return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(function(cacheName) {
            if (cacheName != 'blog-{{ site.github.build_revision }}') {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
            }
        })
        );
    }));
});




self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
    e.respondWith(caches.match(e.request).then(function(response) {
        return response || fetch(e.request);
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any return in your first snippet. is it normal ?

Comment: it return promise resolve, I think fetch only return promise only in first `then`, but it always return promise. I think I need to make all script in the bottom wait until my cache name success. but I don't know to do that

Comment: Where is used staticCacheName ?